# Get property of a Kotlin reflected object with type Any

Tags: kotlin, generics, introspection

I have something like this

```
fun validate(obj1: Any) {
   // Here I am getting the KClass of the object
   val objKClass = obj1::class
   // Here I am casting the object using KClass
   val obj1Cast = objKClass.safeCast(obj1)
   // Then I want to iterate over its properties
   for (prop in objKClass.memberProperties) {
       //And get one BigDecimal? value
       val bigDecimal: BigDecimal? = prop.get(obj1Cast) as BigDecimal?
   }
}
```

This doesn't work, I get in relation to `prop.get(obj1Cast)`:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Nothing
Found:
Any?
```

Is there another way to access the values of the memberProperties and cast them to BigDecimal? (for example) given an object with type Any as the input for my function?

Comment: How about use 'is' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generic type capture to solve this problem.

In your current code, `prop` is of type `KProperty1<out Any, *>`. This is because the type of `obj1` is `Any`, so the type of `objKClass` is `KClass<out Any>`. There are no values that satisfy the type `out Any` when it's used as an input parameter, so you get a compile error.

The first step is to capture the type of `obj1`. We can do that by adding a generic type parameter for it, instead of using `Any`. Let's call the captured type `T`.

```kotlin
fun <T: Any> validate(obj1: T) {
    val objKClass: KClass<out T> = obj1::class
    val obj1Cast = objKClass.safeCast(obj1) ?: return
    for (prop in objKClass.memberProperties) {
        val bigDecimal: BigDecimal? = prop.get(obj1Cast) as BigDecimal?
    }
}
```

Now the type of `prop` is `KProperty1<out T, *>`. This gets us one step closer, but we still have a compile error. That's because `out T` can only be used for an output value, but we want to pass a `T` into a method parameter.

Luckily, the `safeCast` can help us, because it will narrow the type of the value so it exactly matches the type of the class. We just need to give it some help by using a second method to capture the exact type of the class. Let's call the narrower exact type `T2`.

```kotlin
// Here we capture the type of the object as T,
// and get its class as KClass<out T>
fun <T: Any> validate(obj1: T) {
    validate(obj1, obj1::class)
}

// Here we narrow the type of the object from T to T2
fun <T: Any, T2: T> validate(obj1: T, type: KClass<T2>) {
    val obj1Cast = type.safeCast(obj1) ?: return
    for (prop in type.memberProperties) {
        val bigDecimal: BigDecimal? = prop.get(obj1Cast) as BigDecimal?
    }
}
```

Now it works with no compilation errors. For more information on how this works, you can read about "generic type capturing".

Comment: I'm really not sure why `obj1::class` returns `KClass<out T>` instead of `KClass<T>`. It makes this harder than it needs to be 

Comment: It's because that's all that can be guaranteed. The actual KClass for `::class` might be for a subclass of T. For example, if I have `open class Animal` and `class Dog: Animal()` and I did `val animal: Animal = Dog(); validate(animal)`, the `obj1::class` call would return `KClass<Dog>` which can be safely upcast to `KClass<out Animal>` but not `KClass<Animal>`. The only way to get a KClass that doesn't have `out` variance is to call it directly on a class's name, not on a reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this got me in the right direction!